# How does <*> work with Function Applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative, reader

I am trying to figure out with lambda calculus why the function result of the following code

```
(,) <$> (+1) <*> (+1)
```

has type Num a => a -> (a, a) instead of Num a => a -> a -> (a, a)

This is what I have got, am I doing something horribly wrong or is <*> just wired this way?

```
( \x, y -> (,) x y ) <$> ( \x -> x + 1 ) <*> ( \x -> x + 1 )

-- fmap applies first

(\x y -> (,) ((+1) x) y ) <*> ( \x -> x + 1 ) -- substituted the lambda with (+1) for better clarity

-- then goes apply

( \x y -> (,) ((+1) x) ((+1) y) )
```

how do the parameters of the lambda unify and at what point?

Comment: By definition, on this applicative, `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`. Notice that here, if `f` is binary, the result is a unary function. Your last result should be `\x -> (,) ((+1) x) ((+1) x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see types in your example:

```
(,)            <$> (+1)            <*> (+1)
^                  ^                   ^
|                  |                   |
a -> b -> (a, b)   Num a => a -> a     Num a => a -> a
```

Rhs of `(<$>)` and Rhs/Lhs of `(<*>)` must be the Applicative Functor. Your functor is `Num a => (->) a` (the monad Reader).

So, what type will be after `(<$>)` application (Pseudo code):

```
a -> b -> (a, b) <$> Num a => (->) a a ==> Num a => (->) a (b -> (a, b))
```

After `(<*>)` (Pseudo code):

```
Num a => (->) a (b -> (a, b)) <*> Num a => (->) a a ==> Num a => (->) a (a, a)
```

But `Num a => (->) a (a, a)` is equivalent with `Num a => a -> (a, a)`.

---

As @chi wrote at head, the implementation `(<*>)` for type `(->) r` is:

```
(<*>) :: (->) r (a -> b) -> (->) r a -> (->) r b
f <*> g = \r -> f r (g r)
```

And, if you apply, you'll get:

```
(\x y -> (,) x y) <$> (\r -> r + 1) <*> (\r -> r + 1) =
= (\r y -> (,) (r + 1) y) <*> (\r -> r + 1) =
= \r -> (,) (r + 1) (r + 1)
```